# Windows Server 2012 R2 NIC Teaming NFS Share ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, windows-server-2012-r2, network-teaming

Having some strange issues with NIC Teaming when using 2012 R2 NFS for an ESXi 5.5 Datastore.

Firstly I teamed two Intel NIC's on a separate VLAN via a Gigabit switch to two Intel NIC's on ESXi and setup the teaming in vSphere.

This worked OK and was quite fast however under load the network would lock up and cause the Datastore to go offline. I figured this is due to the switch as it has also shown this behaviour whilst connected to a SAN using ISCSI.

Therefore I directly connected the 2012 R2 NIC's and ESXi NIC's together (no switch) and configured the teaming again. The Datastore came back up and was accessible. So this worked and is a lot more stable under load than going via the switch however when teamed it is painfully slow (30/40 seconds to power on a VM), the speed improves if I unplug one of the Ethernet cables and just run down one however I ideally want to team 4 together for 4Gb throughput.

Any thoughts would be appreciated as we are using old kit to try and put together a test/dev environment so we do not have to dip in to the budget and eat in to our production kit.

Comment: You need to show us much more detail - such as the specific teaming setup on the W2012 server and the same on the ESXi host.

Comment: Had a feeling someone would say that... Not in front of that infrastructure at the moment when I am I'll edit the question and add more detail.. Thanks